# Get current time on the iphone in a chosen format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsdate

The following should give me an NSDate object of `9:30`:

```
NSString *dateString = @"09-30";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

How do I get the current time in the same format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
```

Comment: NSString *resultString = [dateFromatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
change dateFromatter to dateFormatter

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *currentDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSDate alloc init will create a date with the current time.  Then, you can use NSDateFormatter stringFromDate for format and present that date.

This:

```
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", date);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
```

Outputs:

```
2011-12-05 07:20:02.994 Craplet[1706:707] 2011-12-05 12:20:02 +0000
2011-12-05 07:20:02.995 Craplet[1706:707] 07-20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"today is :%@", today);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh-mm:ss"];
NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];

NSLog(@"%@", timeString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *currentDate =[NSDate date];
//Your formatter goes here.
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```